# Failure deleting in_memory features ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, delete, in-memory, warning-000117

Here is code and a function giving me grief. Unless issue is noticed specifically with merge and buffer, I am pretty sure my problem lies in the process of creating and overwriting (or deleting) intermediate data in_memory - could be any geoprocessing funciton in arcpy.  I want to find workflow creating intermediary data in_memory that can be run multiple times by overwriting (or deleting) the intermediatary data from in_memory. However the intermediatary data feat_to_buff_<20 or 100>ft is NOT being overwritten.

```
import arcpy
import os

def buffer_range_merge(fp_in, buffer_list, base_dir_out):
    
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    
    # create string to used to create output filename with buffer vals and units
    buffer_string_formatted = [buff_string.replace(' ', '') for buff_string in buffer_list]
    buffer_string_formatted = '_'.join(buffer_string_formatted)

    # if/elif/else block for passing as .shp, full file path, or as layer string
    # Note - have not tried using .shp yet
    if fp_in[-4:] == '.shp':
        fname_orig = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fp_in)[-1])[0]
    # if full file path to feature
    elif '\\' in fp_in:
        fname_orig = os.path.split(fp_in)[-1]
    # if string dragged from TOC directly (in ArcMap mxd)
    else:
        fname_orig = fp_in
    fname_new = '{}_merged_buffers_{}'.format(fname_orig, buffer_string_formatted)
    fp_out = os.path.join(base_dir_out, fname_new)

    # loop through and buffer feature for each paramaeter (string) in buffer_list
    lyr_list = []
    for buff_val in buffer_list:
        lyr = 'in_memory\\buff_{}'.format(buff_val.replace(' ', '_'))
        # accumulate buffered layer names to merge
        lyr_list.append(lyr)
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fp_in, lyr, buffer_distance_or_field = buff_val, dissolve_option = 'ALL')

    # now merge all buffered layers in memory
    arcpy.Merge_management(lyr_list, fp_out)
```

Import and call function  **from Python Console in ArcMap**

```
import file_containing_function

fp_in1 = 'temp_lyr1'
fp_in2 = 'temp_lyr2'
buffer_list = ['20 feet', '100 feet']
base_dir = 'path/to/default.gdb'

file_containing_function.buffer_range_merge(fp_in1, buffer_list, base_dir)
```

This works - I get my desired feature:
`temp_lyr1_merged_buffers_20feet_100feet` which contains two features: 20 and 100 foot buffers of `temp_lyr1` along with the intermediate in_memory layers: `buff_20_feet` and `buff_100_feet`

But when I run it again with a different feature layer:

```
file_containing_function.buffer_range_merge(fp_in2, buffer_list, base_dir)
```

I get the EXACT SAME final merged feature as the first run `temp_lyr1_merged_buffers_20feet_100feet` with a new name:  `temp_lyr2_merged_buffers_20feet_100feet`. 
Apparently `buff_20_feet` and `buff_100_ft` are not being overwritten `in_memory`.

**So why aren't the `in_memory` feature layers being overwritten?**  And yes, I have tried using `arcpy.Delete_management`.

ArcMap 10.6.1

Comment: The problem with your question is you are NOT showing us the real code, you've deliberately obscured the problem by having "path/to/default.gdb" etc. Until you show the true code and not some pseudo code no one can really answer this as the error could be in what you are hiding...

Comment: I appreciate the comment @Hornbydd but my exact code is in a large function with string formatting to concatenate filenames  and extraneous details that I assumed would distract many readers.  I figured generalizing it would solve the issue, but I see your point. I have troubleshot (word?) the basics like filetypes, arguments to arcpy functions and what not already.  But I'll remove the question and repost as you suggest.  Keep your eye out please as you usually address my questions.  Appreciate it...

Comment: You don't have to include your actual code, but the code you do include must be syntactically valid and exhibit the problem with real data. Please DON'T remove the question, just edit it.

Comment: Edited. - hope that helps clarify my question.

Comment: I've just run your code and it works for me! The only difference I did was copy your main buffer_range_merge function into the python console, then define buffer_list and base_dir on new lines in console and finally call your function as such "buffer_range_merge("Export_Output1",buffer_list,base_dir)". So I did not use the `import file_containing_function`. I have ArcMap 10.6.1

Comment: You did indeed!  Yet I messed up the end of question.  Instead of rerunning with new layer - `fp_in2`, I edited `temp_lyr1` vertices and reran `buffer_range_merge(fp_in1,...)` - creating feature with same name as first run.  Perhaps it's `Merge_management` since `temp_lyr1` EXISTS - I have seen posts claiming `Merge_management` behaves like the editing session `merge`, effectively invalidating `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`. Currenly `buffer_100_feet` and `buffer_20_feet` are overwritten (Great!), but `temp_lyr1_merged_buffers_20feet_100feet` is identical to first run - pre vertices edit.